# ETH adress creation time?

Tags: etherscan

Is it possible to find out ETH adress generation time (I have adress and want to find out time of it's creation and if possible also is it was created by exchange)?

Answer (score 2):

All possible ethereum addresses are actually already created. It's kind of like if all the atoms in the universe were a private key, and all you're doing is selecting a random atom in the universe and making it yours. Although it's possible for someone else to select that random atom in the universe, the chances of that actually happening is close to 0% because the number of possibilities is 2^256.

[image: 2^256]

You can however know when the first transaction occurred via a particular public address.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.

An address is derived from the public part of a public/private key pair. The public key is derived from the associated private key, which is generated first.

The *private key* is 256 random bits. You can, if you're so inclined, generate it by flipping a coin 256 times. None of those bits convey any information about when the random number was generated, or who it was generated by. That would be a security hole.

Also note, I can do all this offline, without anyone ever knowing I've done it. My address/key-pair can sit there for years, unused, until I decide to use it. Finding out the first time I *use* my address to send or receive a transaction is a different matter, and can be done, in its simplest form, by looking on a bog-standard block explorer.

Comment: thnx :( and also I can found out that this adres did not exist one year ago for example?

Comment: There's no way of knowing if someone has generated a key-pair that corresponds to an address, no. (Again, because they can do all this offline and not use the address.) You can check whether someone _used_ the address before a year ago by using etherscan.io, but that's the best you can do. Until the address is used, no one can know if it exists.